# Crystal formula to Concatenate city and address field

Tags: vb.net

I have written a formula `{DataField1.City}&"-"&{DataField1.Pin}` in the display string property of `{DataField1.City}` in order to concatenate these to fields but the output is appearing formatted like an amount. For example `Mangalore-567,256.00` but I want `Mangalore-567256`

Answer (score 1):

If `DataField1.Pin` is a number then you could try [`ToText`](http://crystaltricks.com/wordpress/?p=149) to control its formatting.