# Concatenate string and numeric field in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to concatenate city and pincode field in crystal report. I have tried:

```
{datafield1.city}&"-"&{datafield2.pin}
```

It is displaying ex: Mangalore-568,757.00

But I want mangalore-568757

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674858/crystal-formula-to-concatinate-city-and-address-field) question?

Answer (score 5):

```
{datafield1.city}&"-"&totext({datafield2.pin},"#")
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the "#" is the format string for the text conversion.